# <select> vs <ul> and css

Tags: html, css

My introduction to web development was an outdated class my freshman year of highschool. Now after graduating college without really keeping up with that side of the tech stack, so much has changed that I don't recognize anything anymore.

what is the reasoning behind using lists styled with css to behave like the `<select>` tag vs actually using a `<select>` tag? Is the `<select>` tag simply not flexible enough?

Comment: It's hard to style the `select` element. You can't style the items contained within it. With a styled list though you've got much more control over how it will look. That's why a lot of JavaScript plugins use other elements to create this functionality. For example, [Selectize](http://selectize.github.io/selectize.js/), uses Divs and inputs to create the effect.

Comment: I think that ul's acting as select is because you can achieve your own styling that with select it's more hard to get. try styling a select tag, and you will understand it right fast

Comment: This is difficult to answer as the reasons may vary per between each application. It's really the choice between something more generic or more specialised.